# Using Custom metadatype to compare which fields are modified

Tags: custom-metadata

I'm trying to do some actions like calling a class when an only separate set of fields are modified on an object.

### What I did

I'm using trigger.old and trigger.new to compare values of old and new for each and every field to call the class. The challenger here is if I need to add one more field to it I need to repush the whole class for adding one field

### Why I am not doing through point & click

I can use ISchanged from process and builder and perform the action but I need the old and new values to see history.

### What I am trying to do

Create a custom metadatatype with Label and API name and somehow compare this in trigger context to make it scalable.

### Where I am stuck

I have added the label and API name to a map and used Schema.SObjectType.Account.fields.getMap() to get Api name , label pair but I am unable to figure out how to compare these.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There's actually a more appropriate choice here: [Field Sets](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_about_field_sets.htm&type=5). Custom Metadata is a separate type of data, that you don't need to use in this case. You can reference them in code easily.

```
FieldSetMember[] fields = sObjectType.Account.fieldSets.getMap().get('fieldsetname').getFields();
for(Integer i = 0, s = Trigger.new.size(); i < s; i++) {
  for(FieldSetMember fieldMember: fields) {
    sObjectField field = fieldMember.getSObjectField();
    if(Trigger.old[i].get(field) != Trigger.new[i].get(field)) {
      // Do stuff here //
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @sfdcfox . I've implemented my solution with fieldsets and it is working very smooth and ofcourse in scalable format. Really learned new things